# Pandas assign field if condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

just a little help please.
I have this csv structure.

```
login.       user
             user1
             user1
user\002.    this strings comes from the merge
```

I will explain this data frame

I have different fields merged inside `user`, but in specific cases, I want to check if the column `login` is not empty, to replace all the content of `user` for that specific row, with the content of login but stripping out all the characters of the string.
so this is what I would like to have as an output

```
login.       user
             user1
             user1
user\002.    002
```

am new to pandas, and I would like to know how can I check if a field is populated, to copy its data to another one, stripping down some strings from it?

thank you very much for any help you can provide me with.

EDIT:
I do apology if my post wasn't clear enough. Ill try to explain my self better.

my actual csv file look something like this.

```
login.        field1     field2    user
              123456              123456
                         1894673   1894673
              1263546             1263546
                         253647    253647
username\002.            username. username
```

The column user, is a merge between 2 other fields, so what I am doing, I am checking those 2 fields, looking for the userID and I am passing that ID to the user column.

Like in my previous example, my code checks for field1 and field2, and does the merge into user field, in this way I am getting the ID of that user.

But in some row, field1 or field2 contain the actual username of the user, in this case `username`, but if we look at `login` it contain the username AND the userID. This particular case, happens only when the `login` is not empty.

So what I would like to do, is check if the `login` is not empty, to copy its content to user and strip everything before the `\` so my result will be as follow

```
login.        field1     field2    user
              123456               123456
                         1894673   1894673
              1263546              1263546
                         253647    253647
username\002.            username. 002
```

Thank you again

Comment: Please explain how "replace all the content of user for that specific row, with the content of login but stripping out all the characters of the string" doesn't leave you with an empty field?

Comment: thank you very much for you reply, I updated my post with the explanation.

Comment: So, as I understand what you are trying to do.  If field2 contains 'username.' you want to replace the contents of user field with the contents of login field with the characters between '\' and '.' or the end of the string.  Is this correct?